# Why does integrating derivative of arcsecant with x=secu turn into a constant?

Tags: calculus

I was trying to integrate  $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ , which I noticed happens to be the derivative of arcsecant (without the absolute value which I don't care about for the purpose of the question) by substituting x = sec(u), dx = sec(u)tan(u) du, which gave me

$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} =$$
$$\int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)du}{sec(u)\sqrt{sec^2(u)-1}} =$$
$$\int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)du}{sec(u)\sqrt{tan^2(u)}} =$$
$$\int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)du}{sec(u)tan(u)} =$$
$$\int 1 = 0$$

which is obviously nonsense. Where did my calculation go wrong? If my calculations are not wrong, is there some rule of substitutions and what is not allowed to be substituted, and if so why is this the case?

Comment: The integral of $1$ is not $0$, it would be $u+C$ ($C$ is an arbitrary constant) in this case. $u=\sec^{-1}(x)$ as expected.

Comment: Oh my god I am so stupid thank you I was staring at this for like two hours

Comment: It is good to avoid weird functions like arcsecant. Attempt to use only arctan, arcsin, arccos, the two last ones being already sufficiently "tricky"...